# Removed local branch and wrote over it with remote

Tags: git

By accident I deleted local branch. Then I wrote over it with remote branch (same name), now all of the changes for the story are gone..

Is there any way to restoring the local branch i deleted?

```
   $ git branch -D branch-name
   $ git branch checkout branch-name
```

*Help appreciated A lot*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make any commits while on your original local branch? If so they might still be visible with `git log` or `git reflog`. If the most recent commit is still there you can apply it to the branch that you just created.

There's also a chance that the commits might accessible using `git fsck --full` to detect if they are considered a dangling git object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the reflog. If @54N1 didn't perform any other commands, this should be as simple as `git checkout HEAD@{2}` (look at `git reflog` before). One other possibility is: if you have written somewhere the sha-1 of a previous commit (ideally the latest one), you should still be able to `git checkout <sha-1>` and branch from here.